# Python Jupyter Notebook not applying function correctly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a jupyter notebook in which I am using the logistic function to return an array that is normalized.

Code:

```
import math
import numpy as np

# takes a list of numbers as input
def logistic_transform(nums):
    e = math.e
    print(e)
    print(nums)
    for num in nums:
        num = 1 / 1 + (e ** num)
    return nums

input = [1, 2, 3]
test = logistic_transform(input)
print(test)
```

The output is:

```
2.718281828459045
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

**Why are the changes not being applied to the values in `input[]` ?**

Comment: use `return num`  instead of `return nums`. You are returning the input only. I would suggest define num as list and append the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your logistic function doesn't make sense,
It should be something like, I guess:

```
(1 / (1 + (e ** (-num)))
```

What you are doing is taking out an element saving it in a variable `num` and updating the variable `num`, and not updating it in the list `nums`.

Either use list comprehension:

`nums = [(1 / (1 + (e ** (-num)))) for num in nums]`

or update the list like

```
for num in range(len(nums)):
    nums[num] = 1 /(1 + (e ** (-nums[num])))
```

Here, this should work fine:

```
import math
def logistic_transform(nums):
    e = math.e
    print(e)
    print(nums)
    nums = [(1 / (1 + (e ** (-num)))) for num in nums]
    return nums

input = [1, 2, 3]
test = logistic_transform(input)
print(test)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback. I think the solution Ashlou gave me is good. Are you saying my logistic function returns the incorrect values? Or is it just not following best practices?

Comment: ur function would return incorrect values. check out the parentheses u r using. U can see in the above answer as per the formulae, it should be going towards 0 when u increase `num`. I mean its obvious.

Comment: also a standard logistic sigmoid function is:
**1/(1+e^(-x))**

Comment: Oh haha yeah it should definitely be getting smaller. And you're right I guess it should be `-num` instead of `num` right (which WOULD cause the numbers to get bigger)?

Answer (score 1):

Just put your results in another list!

```
import math
import numpy as np
p_num =[]
# takes a list of numbers as input
def logistic_transform(nums):
    e = math.e
    print('e',e)
    print('nums',nums)
    for num in nums:
        p_num.append(1 / 1 + (e ** num))
return  p_num

input = [1, 2, 3]
test = logistic_transform(input)
print('test',test)
```

e 2.718281828459045

nums [1, 2, 3]

test [3.718281828459045, 8.389056098930649, 21.085536923187664]

Answer (score 0):

What u do just get a new list,try a new list:

```
    new_list = []
    for num in nuns:
        #do ur stuff
        new_list.append(num)
    return new_list
```